# How to make a .plist for a mac applications

Tags: java, macos, plist, .app

I'm trying to turn a java program into a mac .app file, or more accurately, a native mac application. This requires a .plist file (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)) but I can't seem to find anywhere that works in telling me how to make one. I set up the directories as they specified, and my application debugs properly. Its just every time I try to open the application, it immediately shuts down. Does anyone know how to make a (minimalist even, for now) working plist file?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: For the programming. But as far as I've found, it doesn't have anything that would make an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project and select Export.  Assuming you on using a Mac, there will be an option to output an application bundle.

[image]

Once you have created the app bundle (which itself is just a directory), go here to find the Info.plist file:

```
MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

From there you can edit the plist, if you need to.

Comment: That works great, thank you! Another question: now the app (which debugged fine) just opens and immediately shuts down. Is that an issue with the plist, or something else?